# Cucumber h1 test passing but shouldn't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber

i am just starting to use cucumber and like it so far however there is one issue that seems very basic that I can't work out.  I am doing a very basic test of my homepage with the following:

home_pages.feature

```
Feature: Viewer visits the Home Page
        In order to read the page
        As a viewer
        I want to see the home page of my app

    Scenario: View home page
        Given I am on the home page
        Then I should see "Test" in the selector "h1"

    Scenario: Check Home Page Links
        Given I am on the home page
        Then I should see "How It Works" in a link
        And I should see "Sign Up" in a link
        And I should see "Log In" in a link
```

and cr1_steps.rb

```
Given /^I am on the home page$/ do
  visit root_path
end

Then /^I should see "([^"]*)" in the selector "([^"]*)"$/ do |text, selector|
  page.should have_selector selector, content: text
end

Then /^I should see "([^"]*)" in a link$/ do |text|
    page.should have_link text
end
```

home.html.erb

```
<div class="center hero-unit">
  <h1>Working</h1>
    <p>testing testing testing</p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
        Click This
      </a>
 </div>
  <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/360x268" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

However cucumber is passing even though the "h1" selector has "Working" in the home.html.erb, where as it should fail as I am testing for "h1"Test  Any ideas why this could be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a `:content` option in the Capybara documentation for `#has_selector?`

Try `text: text` instead.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean here, what would I be replacing.  Could you also point me towards the documentation.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: `page.should have_selector(selector, text: text)` http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_selector%3F-instance_method